# Debugger inside React Context API Consumer block - this is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, this

I am trying to debug a component using [Context API Consumer](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#consumer) inside `render` method on browser dev tools. If i place break-point inside `Consumer` block, i can't print props etc. on console dynamically as `this` is `undefined`. Normally running this works fine, but while debugging only value of `this` is `undefined`. Following is sample render method of component.

```
  componentMethod = () => {
      console.log(this.props.name); //Placing breakpoint here, value is this is defined
  }

  render() {
        return (
            <div className={styles.container}>
                <div>
                    <h4>{this.props.name}</h4>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.block}>
                    <MyComponent.Consumer>
                        {
                            ({ firstParam, secondParam }) =>
                                <AotherComponent
                                    firstParam={firstParam}
                                    secondParam={secondParam}
                                    thirdParam={this.props.name}
                                />
                        }
                    </MyComponent.Consumer>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
  }
```

I could be related fat arrow use here, but I am able to get value of this while using break-point in `componentMethod`. Is there a way to `bind` `this` for `Consumer` block?

Comment: From your code it looks like: props.name is a prop of the `component` you are showing, as well as the componentMethod you have bound to. Your `consumer`  doesn't seem to have anything to do with it. Btw, you can also `console.log` in the `render` method, before the return. Can you clarify your problem statement a bit more?

Comment: Placing break point just outside Context Consumer kind of works inside render method. I am able to see the props on console while debugging using breakpoints. There are alternate ways to debug using console.log statements. But just to see along with break-point, it seems its not showing correct value inside Context consumer.

Comment: ah, I see. I have not run into this problem as I declare the the consumer mapping IN the AnotherComponent file, by using the `export default props => <Consumer>... ` construct. That way my usage of consumer is abstracted away and I have the props come in. AnotherComponent can be a simple react component. I will try to update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, however, your question doesn't give enough context on what you are trying to solve. It would be better if you shared the `Provider` implementation as well and where you use it.

```
render() {
        const { name } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className={styles.container}>
                <div>
                    <h4>{name}</h4>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.block}>
                    <MyComponent.Consumer>
                        {
                            ({ firstParam, secondParam }) =>
                                <AotherComponent
                                    firstParam={firstParam}
                                    secondParam={secondParam}
                                    thirdParam={name}
                                />
                        }
                    </MyComponent.Consumer>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
  }
```

Comment: Jjagwe, the functionality is working, I think there is no change in required (value is not undefined). But for debugging purpose, when I am running application on browser, I want to debug few things in run time that what is value of particular variable by placing breakpoint. I could use console logs to see values, but what i am trying is to use breakpoint and see the value.

Comment: Oh, I get. I think its just a misinterpretation of `this` because what is rendered in the provider is a component its self. That's why I opted for destructuring out the name value from props first and passing it to `AnotherComponent` rendered in the children component of the consumer without using `this`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are interested in knowing what your consumer is passing down to your component during execution. There are two ways to accomplish it.

### Hard Way

Let us breakdown how the consumer works (using your sample). That may help you with finding the right place to debug.

in your `render()` method, you have a `<MyComponent.Consumer>` call. The new Context Consumer API is built on the [render-prop pattern](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html#using-props-other-than-render).

Important thing to remember about the render-prop pattern is that: it is a `function` call. This function should return something which react can consider while rendering the tree.

Since it is a function call, you **can** put your console.log statements before your element. You will have to add an explicit `return` statement though.

As to why it is `undefined` in your method. I am assuming that the `componentMethod` is not a lifecycle method, so it is possible that `this` or `this.props`is undefined based on **how** you are invoking that method. I do not see it invoked anywhere in your render method.

### Eas(y/ier) Way:

Use [react dev tools](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools) browser extension. You can look up all components by *name*. On clicking them you can see the props and state and even the context (as far as I remember). You can even change the values and see react *react* to it!